import python libraries in jinja2 templates
I have this template:
% template.tmpl file:
% set result = fractions.Fraction(a*d + b*c, b*d) %}
The solution of ${{a}}/{{b}} + {{c}}/{{d}}$ is ${{a * d + b*c}}/{{b*d}} = {{result.numerator}}/{{result.denominator}}$ 

which I invoke by
from jinja2 import Template
import fractions

with open("c.jinja") as f:
    t = Template(f.read())
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 4
    d = 5
    print(t.render(a = a, b = b, c=c, d=d))

I get
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'fractions' is undefined

but I want
The solution of $2/3 + 4/5$ is $22/15=22/15$.

Is this possible to achieve that?

Sooo add fractions=fractions ? Are you sure your template is correct?

It can be done in two ways.

Calculate the result in Python code and then pass it as a parameter to the template.
You can pass the fractions module as a parameter to the template.

Folder structure:
.
├── c.jinja
└── template_example.py

Option 1: Pass result to the template:
template_example.py:
from jinja2 import Template
import fractions

with open("c.jinja") as f:
    t = Template(f.read())
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 4
    d = 5
    result = fractions.Fraction(a * d + b * c, b * d)
    print(t.render(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, result=result))

c.jinja:
The solution of ${{a}}/{{b}} + {{c}}/{{d}}$ is ${{a * d + b*c}}/{{b*d}} = {{result.numerator}}/{{result.denominator}}$

Option 2: Pass the fractions:
template_example.py:
from jinja2 import Template
import fractions

with open("c.jinja") as f:
    t = Template(f.read())
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 4
    d = 5
    print(t.render(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, fractions=fractions))

c.jinja:
{% set result = fractions.Fraction(a*d + b*c, b*d) %}
The solution of ${{a}}/{{b}} + {{c}}/{{d}}$ is ${{a * d + b*c}}/{{b*d}} = {{result.numerator}}/{{result.denominator}}$

Output for both options:
The solution of $2/3 + 4/5$ is $22/15 = 22/15$

I would recommend Option 1: Pass the result to the template. This approach keeps the template focused on its primary role: rendering text with provided data, while the Python code handles all the computations.

I knew the option to pass result as a parameter of the template, but I "need" your option 2, because with some params, I need to calculate some other stuff and in option 1, there is more calculations outside template. Particulary, I like very much makotemplates which allows to embed all python code in the template, but it has some cons: there is no option to no returning carriage after control structure or calling parameter: something like This is a sum {% 1 + 1 %} in jinja is impossible with mako without putting a returning carriage after the sum.

Sorry, I mean control structures like {% if something %} bla {% endif %} something else. In mako, there is no possibility to put something else next to control code.
